# why blazor dotnet core 3.1 webassembly client and shared projects are netstandard 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

created blazor web assembly client and server sides in  core3.1, when project created we have 3 related projects,

- server project => netcoreapp3.1
- client project => netstandard2.1
- shared project => netstandard2.1

why two other projects are netstandard2.1? I need a change from netstandard2.1 to core3.1.

why client and shared projects are netstandard2.1 ? can I change to netcore3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.net-core 3.x is a superset of .net-standard 2.x .

A server project needs to be .net core because that is what asp.net core requires.

Blazor/Wasm runs on the sub-set .net-standard, and even then it throws NotSuportedException for features unavailable in a Browser. Like a simple `File.ReadAllText()`.

Implementing Blazor in .net-core would require changes in Mono and only lead to more empty promises. It has to fit in the Browser 'sandbox' environment.

> I need a change from netstandard2.1 to core3.1.

Explain why (you think) you need that. That is where the real problem is and maybe the solution.

> can I change to netcore3.1?

No.

Comment: Because I use clean architecture and I use the netcore libraries.https://imgur.com/0Ryfc2Y

Comment: I'm not sure if that refers to Blazor, probably MVC. Different frameworks will lead to different Shared layers. You can do Clean Arch with everything, you don't need Core per se.

Answer (score 4):

> server project => netcoreapp3.1

Server projects are netcoreapp3.1 because they run on the server

> client project => netstandard2.1

Client projects are netstandard2.1 because they run on the client (browser) by the mono runtime (mono.wasm), which is .Net, not .Net Core. So you cannot change  it from netstandard2.1 to core3.1.

> shared project => netstandard2.1

Is shared by both the client project and the server project, so you cannot change to netcore3.1, as the client project can only use netstandard2.1

Hope this helps...